# GetChar() function strange

Tags: c, io, getchar

- List item

I have a problem using `getchar()` method.What I am trying is to compute a small assembly simulator with 8 commands that are written by the user under the form `ADD Rx Ry` where `Rx` and `Ry` are the registers. I am not allowed to use strings nor arrays so the only option is to read char by char.

My problem is that I don't know how to read multiple characters from one line of input text and put it in variables.For example, `ADD Rx Ry` I want to store `A` in `ch1`, `D` in `ch2` and `D` in `ch3` then skip space verify `R` and store `x` in a variable and then the same for `y`.

The strange thing is that when I input the second command after the initial one, the program that is shown below just won't show the exact same print values(the printing is just for debugging)

```
do{
  ch1=getchar();
  ch2=getchar();
  ch3=getchar();
  if(ch1=='E' && ch2=='N'&& ch3=='D'){
    break;
  }
    printf("%c",ch1);
    printf("%c",ch2);
    printf("%c",ch3);
}while(1);
```

Comment: What input do you give? Does it include newlines? Do you read the newline? What output did you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: You have to read the newline too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user types "ADD Rx Ry", he will hit Enter.

`getchar()` consumes one character at a time.

So, in order to consume this input, you need to call `getchar()` 8 times, 3 for "ADD", 2 for the whitespaces and 4 for the registers.

Now you want to input "ADD Ri Rj", so you think that you will need to call `getchar()` 8 times again.

The first call of `getchar()` will consume the trailing newline from the previous input (when the user hit Enter)! It will not consume 'A', as you would hope.

As a result, when "END" is typed, there are trailing newlines and characters from previous inputs (if any) that will be consumed by `getchar()`.

So, just consume the trailing newline (and continue your loop, since you don't want to process the newline character, just to consume it), like this:

```
do {
  ch1 = getchar();
  if(ch1 == '\n')
    continue;
  ch2 = getchar();
  if(ch2 == '\n')
    continue;
  ch3 = getchar();
  if(ch3 == '\n')
    continue;
  ch4 = getchar();
  if(ch4 == '\n')
    continue;

  if(ch1=='E' && ch2=='N'&& ch3=='D') {
    break;
  }
} while(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the newline too. Also, you have to flush `stdin` to remove any excess output after scanning. If you can't use strings nor arrays, and the only option is to use `getchar`, you will have no manually manage the buffer of 4 characters, which is not going to be pretty.

```
char ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4;
do {
    ch1 = getchar(); if (ch1 == '\n') continue;
    ch2 = getchar(); if (ch2 == '\n') continue;
    ch3 = getchar(); if (ch3 == '\n') continue;
    ch4 = getchar(); if (ch4 != '\n') continue;
    if (ch1 == 'E' && ch2 == 'N' && ch3 == 'D' && ch4 == '\n') break;
} while (1);
```

What happens when you don't account for the newline and flushing `stdin` is this:

1. User enters `ADD\n` (4 characters).
2. `ADD` is scanned, `ch1` contains `'A'`, `ch2` contains `'D'`, `ch3` contains `'D'`. `'\n'` is left in the `stdin`.
3. Next iteration comes. User enters `ADD\n` again.
4. However, there is `'\n'` left in `stdin` from the previous scan, so `ch1` contains `'\n'`, `ch2` contains `'A'`, `ch3` contains `'D'` and there is `D\n` leftover in `stdin`.

Comment: @Bob__ And? My code is not identical to OP's code because the OP's code is broken.

Answer (score 0):

When you start typing data into the terminal, say first you typed "ADD\n",

- A is stored in ch1
- D is stored in ch2
- D is stored in ch3

and than '\n' is sent to the buffer. Now second time you start typing new set of characters, say "SUB", getchar() starts reading from the buffer and the first character it encounters is the '\n', and so on, 
hence

- ch1 = '\n'
- ch2 = 'S'
- ch3 = 'U'

A better fix to a problem is add one getchar() after all the three getchar()s that will consume the extra '\n' and will not print the same.

```
do{
   ch1=getchar();
   ch2=getchar();
   ch3=getchar();
   getchar();

 if(ch1=='E' && ch2=='N'&& ch3=='D'){
    break;
  }
    printf("%c",ch1);
    printf("%c",ch2);
    printf("%c",ch3);
}while(1);
return 0;
```

}